# How can I implement grails Url Mapping for subdomains

Tags: url, grails, subdomain, url-routing

I want to implement Url mapping for subdomains like sub.mysite.com sub2.mysite.com in grails.
The best solution for now is to do some rewriting via nginx/lighttpd.
But is it possible via native grails Url mapping features ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UrlMappings are not meant for full URL rewrite like in web server. The UM are only for the the part of URL after "server URL" (application root). If the rewrite rules in web server are not sufficient for you, you can also implement your own filter and register it to the web.xml, but your post does not provide enough information to decide ;-)